# Square Root for Bigint in F#

Tags: f#, biginteger

Is there a way to get the square root of a big integer?  I am dealing with numbers that are much too large for int64 to handle so bigint is a must.

I was considering the idea of implementing it myself using the Babylonian method, but want to know if there are any built in functions for this first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also wanted this. (In my case I could avoid it, since it was just for a comparason, I squared both sides)

Answer (score 2):

You can use newton's method on any scalar.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

-- MarkusQ

P.S. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: I believe Newton's method is aka Babylonian method.

Comment: Yes, that's what he said he was considering using.  When I learned it it was always called Newton's method, so when I read "Babylonian method," think, and retransmit it always comes out as "Newton's method."

I have stopped calling CDs "records" though, so there's hope for me.

Comment: It was always Newton's method to me, too.  I only recently learned about the alias.

Comment: when talking about finding Square roots i've always heard it called the Babylonian method.

Answer (score 0):

[Happy Square Root Day](http://www.sciam.com/blog/60-second-science/post.cfm?id=square-root-day-3309-is-upon-us-2009-03-03) to you too :).

I don't think there is built-in in bigint