# Fastest method implementing number sqare root in string (1000000 digits)

Tags: algorithm

What is fastest algorithm implementing a square root of decimal contained in strings.
This decimal can have 1000000 digits.

Anyone can tell me something about it?

Comment: Did you solve the other problem? The multiplication one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's method should work fine for you: [Square Root for Bigint in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608514/square-root-for-bigint-in-f) .

Newton's method requires big decimal division.  A somewhat simpler method which requires only squaring is just binary search on the square root.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'lsqrt' (Just google for some code) and adjust it for your number type. I used the same approach to deal with big numbers in IronScheme.

Seems to work well.

Edit:

This returns an 'integer' root and a remainder.

Answer (score 0):

[**BigSquareRoot**](http://www.merriampark.com/bigsqrt.htm)